# Initializing a qlist with qhash->keys

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt4

Can there occur a bad initialization while doing the following things:

```
pdList = new QList<QString>(somehash->keys());
```

where,

```
pdList = QList<QString>*
somehash = QHash<QString,QList<someobject*> > *
```

this operation happens at startup in constructor.

The reason for asking is sometimes i get a crash while doing

```
pdlist->contains(someqstring)
```

rigth after the constructor is called.
The crash is in

/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.6.3-410wrl/include/QtCore/qlist.h:93

/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.6.3-410wrl/include/QtCore/qlist.h:757

Comment: Please post the complete code of your constructor. I suspect it may be the order of initialization.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `QList< QString >`, as opposed to `QList(QString)`.

Comment: He should really be using QStringList... http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstringlist.html

Comment: i have used what you have said, the reason for writing QList(QString) is the editor here,does not allow me to put < tags around QString

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to template usage like below . You should use <> characters:

```
QHash<QString,QList<someObject*> > somehash;
//Populate your hash here

//Populate list with keys
QList<QString> pdList (somehash.keys());
```

Answer (score 0):

*Preliminary guess until additional code is provided.*

Perhaps you are depending on the order of initialization that is invalid. Some variant of the following:

```
class MyClass {
public:
  MyClass() :
    somehash(new QHash<QString, QList<MyClass*> >()),
    pdList(new QList<QString>(somehash->keys())) {}
private:
  QList<QString> *pdList;
  QHash<QString, QList<MyClass*> > *somehash;
};
```

`pdList` will always be initialized before `somehash`. It is the order they are listed as data members, not in the constructor, that determines it. Some compilers will let you put them in the incorrect order in the constructor initialization list; others will not.

This is just a guess; if you provide more information, the community will be better able to help.